# Defining a macro for nodes in a qtree

Tags: macros, qtree

I'm using the `qtree` package to make linguistic c-structure trees. Consider the following simple tree:

[image: A constituent structure tree with an IP_1 node, splitting into a DP_2 node with annotation (up SUBJ) = down, and a VP_3 node with annotation up = down]

generated by the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{qtree}

% shorthands for annotations below nodes
\newcommand{\subj}{\textsc{subj}}
\newcommand{\up}{$\uparrow$~}
\newcommand{\down}{$\downarrow$~}
\newcommand{\updown}{$\uparrow\,=\,\downarrow$}

\begin{document}

\Tree [ .{IP_{1}} [ .{DP_{2} \\ (\up \subj) = \down} ] [ .{VP_{3} \\ \updown} ] ]

\end{document}
```

I've been trying to make a macro for these qtree nodes because they follow the same structure each time. Moreover, about 60% of the time, the annotation below the node is `\updown`, so that could be a default argument to the macro. So far I have this:

```
\newcommand{\node}[3][\updown]{ .{#2_{#3} \\ #1} }
```

so the above tree would be:

```
\Tree [ \node{}{IP}{1} [ \node{(\up \subj) = \down)}{DP}{2} ] [ \node{VP}{3} ] ]
```

but this gives me errors:

```
Extra }, or forgotten $.
Missing } inserted.
```

I don't understand what I'm missing here.

Extra question, would it be able to do automatic numbering instead of having to pass those indices as an argument? The numbering goes left-to-right in the tree code (so depth-first in the tree itself).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se and thanks for adding a minimal example document with your question. `qtree` is a very old package with limited possibilities for things like auto numbering. I would suggest switching to `forest`. (I suspect someone will likely give you a `forest` solution anyway...)

Comment: The qtree parser explicitly looks for brackets, dots and spaces; so you can't include the dot in the definition of `\node` without piling on a whole lot of `\expandafter` magic. So the dot should stay explicit, e.g. `[.\node{IP}{1} [ ...`. But that's not enough by itself, something else also gets in the way and i'm not sure what. :-(